# Send a JavaScript variable to PHP without POST

Tags: javascript, php

I have a HTML modal containing a form with a select tag and an input text.

Select options are extracted from a database like this.

```
<select id="select_1" name="select_1">
   <?php
```

A code that access to DB

```
      $sql = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM my_table;');
      while(@$fetch = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
          $id = $fetch['id'];
          $name= $fetch['name'];
    ?>                                              
    <option id="<?php echo $id ; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
</select>

<input type="text" id="input_1">
```

What I'm trying to do is when I choose an option from the select tag I want to output a field from a database relative to that select option in an input text.

For example let's pretend that `my_table` is defined this way and contains these:

```
|      id      |      name      |      price      |
+--------------+----------------+-----------------+
|      1       |      A         |      500        |
|      2       |      B         |      1000       |
```

My select tag will then contains the two options A & B:

```
<Option 1> A
<Option 2> B
```

When I select Option 1 (A) I want to output it's price in the input text so it will contain 500.

When I select Option 2 (B) 1000 will be output in the input text.

How Can I do that without submiting the form with POST and without closing the MODAL?

Comment: You are trying to not reload the page, or just not use the `POST` method? There is the `GET` method, but it sounds like AJAX is what you are after. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: In php, set the value of each option to its price.  In javascript, set a change handler on the select which updates your text box with the selected option’s value.  No ajax needed.

Comment: You can print the price as a property like data-price="<?php echo $fetch['price']; ?>" and then use javascript to read the price value and print it into the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do

```
  <select id="select_1" name="select_1">
<?php
   $sql = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM my_table;');
   while($fetch = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>                      
   <option id="opt-<?php echo $fetch['id']; ?>" data-price="<?php echo $fetch['price']; ?>" ><?php echo $fetch['name']; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="input_1">
```

Then you can use (jQuery)

```
$('#select_1').on('change', function(){
     $('#input_1').val($(this).find('option:selected').data('price'));
});
```

There is actually no need for AJAX, because the price comes from the same table. You can simply store it as a data attribute and then access it when the select changes.

But, remember it's an attribute of the `option` not the `select`.  So you need to get the `option` that is `selected`.  Which we can do with the sudo-selector `:selected`

```js
$('#select_1').on('change', function(){
     $('#input_1').val($(this).find('option:selected').data('price'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select_1" name="select_1">     
   <option id="opt-0" data-price="" >Pick an Option</option>                  
   <option id="opt-1" data-price="500" >A</option>
   <option id="opt-2" data-price="1000" >B</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="input_1">
```

P.S. You are not really supposed to start an id with a number.  So I added `opt-` to it.

Also you could just do this (use the value attribute):

```
    <select id="select_1" name="select_1">
<?php
   $sql = $bdd->query('SELECT * FROM my_table;');
   while($fetch = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>                               
   <option id="opt-<?php echo $fetch['id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $fetch['price']; ?>" ><?php echo $fetch['name']; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
  </select>
```

I don't really see the need for the text input.  Because when you submit this the value of `select_1` in the Post or Get part of the submission will be the value of the select not the text of it.

But with out more about what you are doing, who can say.

Comment: What's this dollar. Php? Most confusing answer is yours yet.

Comment: It's jQuery, which makes life a whole lot easier

Comment: No, it isn't for beginners, mixing php, and unclear pseudo javascript without including the lib, this is very misleading.  
In base ecma js: 
select.onchange = (function(){input1 = select_1.value }) 
And that's all.

Comment: Except its not the value of `select_1`, but whatever.  Run the snipit it works.

Comment: That is generic, and shorter.

Comment: @Cryptopat - if you think you can do a more appropriate answer, then by all means post away.

Comment: This did the job. Thanks

Comment: I posted as asked. I don't think to be wrong here. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using javascript or Jquery with and AJAX request.

Example using Jquery:

```
$(document).on('change','#select_1',function({
 var value = $(this).value;

  //DO your ajax request here and send the value inside the data

})
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you have the values already loaded, passed into the select options values, using [GlobalEventHandlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers) and an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
select_1.onchange = (()=> {
  input_1.value = select_1.value
})
```

```html
<select id="select_1">
   <option value="1" selected> A </option>
   <option value="2"> B </option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="input_1" value="1">
```